# get files from a shared folder with password from a anohter computer with batch file

Tags: batch

I'm using a **.bat** file to get some files from a shared folder on another computer in the same network. My challenge is that the shared folder is password protected. Is there a way to write **username** and **password** in a batch file when getting files from a shared folder located on another computer?

```
@echo off
Move /Y \\path\to\files\*.csv \\path\to\local\folder\
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
net use X: \\path\to\files\ /user:<username> <password>
move /y x:\*.csv \\path\to\local\folder\
net use x: /d
pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfect. the only thing i need to modify is to remove the last \ from \\path\to\files\, otherwise I got "system error 67 has occurred".